# Power Generalized Weibull (PGW) Distribution

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, weibull-distribution

I'm trying to understand Power Generalized Weibull (PGW) distribution for my final project. PGW distribution is the generalization of Weibull distribution.

The cdf of PGW distribution is $G(x) = 1 - e^{1-(1+\lambda x^\beta)^\alpha}$, for $x > 0, \lambda, \beta, \alpha > 0$. Note that $\lambda$ is the scale parameter and $\beta, \alpha$ are the shape parameters. When $\alpha = 1$, it becomes the Weibull distribution with parameters $\lambda$ and $\beta$.

So, my question is how to construct PGW distribution from Weibull distribution (since it is the generalization of Weibull distribution)? What kind of methods that we use? I've been thinking and searching this for 2 weeks, but still can't find the answer. Please anyone let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stats exchange! Can you give a few more specifics about what you are hoping for in an answer? You have given both the definition of the PGW and the special case of the Weibull in your example. What do you mean by "construct"?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I hope something like this. For example, we have Alpha Power Weibull Distribution. This distribution comes from Weibull distribution by doing the alpha power transformation. Another example, the Weibull-Lindley distribution. To construct this distribution, we use Transformed-Transformer method. So, since PGW distribution is generalization of Weibull distribution, what method that we use to get PGW distribution from Weibull distribution? I hope you understand what I mean. Thanks!

Comment: The scale parameter is $\lambda^{1/\beta},$ not $\lambda.$  Regardless, you can obtain the distribution of $X^\beta$ (up to scale) by applying a Box-Cox transformation of parameter $1/\alpha$ to an exponential variable that has been shifted by $1.$  Thus, you can understand much about $X$ once you have developed intuition for shifting, for the Box-Cox transformation, and power transformations.  What, then, do you want to learn about $X$?  What properties do you need to understand or derive?

Comment: For the scale parameter, the paper says that it is $\lambda$, so I just follow it. What I want to learn is how do we get the PGW distribution from Weibull distribution? In other words, given the cdf of Weibull distribution, then what can we do (the methods) to get the cdf of PGW distribution as I stated above? Maybe there are some transformation methods that I don't know